# How to support Swift Macro in a project integrated by CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-macro

I am exploring the usage of Swift Macro in my CocoaPods-integrated project. I have successfully created a custom macro by following the instructions, and it functions properly in the host project. However, in the `Pods` project, I am unable to import `CustomMacro` for all the frameworks and development pods.

At this point, I am curious if there is a workaround that supports both CocoaPods and Swift Package Macro.

And also I found a Github thread discussing about a similiar topic: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11942 , but there's no further conclusion.

So please help to give some advises about how to use Swift Macro in CocoaPods project if you have any experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @Soumuya Mahunt and some other [post](https://www.polpiella.dev/binary-swift-macros) and [discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-import-macros-using-methods-other-than-swiftpm/66645), I successfully integrate the Swift Macro to a CocoaPods managed project and its all pods. All the details and steps can be found in [this blog](https://mioke.github.io/posts/How-to-make-macro-available-from-CocoaPods/) or the [demo project](https://github.com/Mioke/SwiftyArchitectureMacros).

The macro pod can be easily used by a project target or a development pod target.

```swift
import MyMacro

let desc = #stringify(1 + 1)
```

For a development pod target or remote pod target, there would be some tricks to make it possible, add the following `post_install` script in the `Podfile` will be fine.

```rb
installer_representation.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] = "$(inherited) -load-plugin-executable #{macro_product_folder}/release/SwiftyArchitectureMacros#SwiftyArchitectureMacros"
end
```

Please see [the blog](https://mioke.github.io/posts/How-to-make-macro-available-from-CocoaPods/) for detail.

Comment: Disappointed in not getting credited in your blog post, even if it just copies most of the content from mine.

Comment: Sorry about your feelings, but I actually have marked the your blog and page link in my post. The `podspec` script configuration part is copied from your idea, but actually not all what I want to achive, the important part is not only the host project can use the macro, but also other pods or local development pods can use the macro too. I tried your `MetaCodable` but it can't be built at that moment, and then I start to study it myself, and this blog is about what I met when study the solution, not just your blog's copy.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to distribute your macro library with CocoaPods, you have to build the macro target as an executable and provide that to the app/user target as:

> -load-plugin-executable #
> Path to an executable compiler plugins and providing module names such as macros

I have written a step-by-step detailed article on this [here](https://soumyamahunt.medium.com/support-swift-macros-with-cocoapods-3911f9317042). You can also see this in action as part of my [MetaCodable](https://github.com/SwiftyLab/MetaCodable) library.

Comment: Really appreciate your information.